# How to display number with first digit as 0(Zero) in Excel using Aspose Cells

Tags: c#, aspose-cells

I need to display '0565' in Downloaded Excel. In datatable the value is '0565' but after assigning datatable to the worksheet, the downloaded excel shows value as '565'. It's an id I need to display it as it is '0565'. Below is my code

```
     DataTable dtExcelData = GetDataTableValue(); 
     dtExcelData.TableName = psPlanNo + "Template";

        var workbook = new Workbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];         
        worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dtExcelData, true, 0, 0, true,true); 
        worksheet.AutoFilter.Range = worksheet.Cells.FirstCell.Name + ":" + worksheet.Cells.LastCell.Name;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + psPlanNo + psSuffix + ".xlsx");
        worksheet.AutoFitColumns();

        Aspose.Cells.Style style = worksheet.Cells["A1"].GetStyle();
        style.ForegroundThemeColor = new ThemeColor(ThemeColorType.Accent1, 0);
        style.Font.Color = Color.White;
        style.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;

        for (int lnColumn = 0; lnColumn <= worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn;  lnColumn++)
            worksheet.Cells[0, lnColumn].SetStyle(style);

        Cells cells = worksheet.Cells;
        Aspose.Cells.Style fontStyle = new Aspose.Cells.Style();
        Aspose.Cells.Style stylefont = workbook.Styles[workbook.Styles.Add()];
        stylefont.Font.Name = "Calibri";
        stylefont.Font.Size = 12;
        StyleFlag flag = new StyleFlag();
        flag.FontName = true;
        flag.FontSize = true;
        cells.ApplyStyle(stylefont, flag);

      using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Save(memoryStream, SaveFormat.Xlsx);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

The highlighted line is to assign dataset value to the worksheet and to display string to numbers in Excel. 
If I use this code

```
  worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dtExcelData, true, 0, 0, true,false);
```

I will get '0565' but there are some columns which should be in number format that will also be converted into text.

Is there any other alternative for my problem???? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Please set the last parameter from true to false.

i.e.

```
worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dtExcelData, true, 0, 0, true, false);
```

and it should fix your issue. The last parameter means convertStringToNumber, if you set it false, then it will not convert string into number.

If you don't want to use this property, then please assign `'` before your numerical string i.e.

```
0555
```

should be like

```
'0055
```

And it will work fine then.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I don't want to use both the technique. is there any other solution??

Comment: There is another method that converts all the string values into numbers, it is also not a good fit but may be you could make use of it. i.e. worksheet.Cells.ConvertStringToNumericValue();

Comment: Another Solution for your Requirement:

You may use custom formatting to make the value be formatted with leading zeros. Such as Style.Custom="0000";